# Using COM Object in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, com

I have Visual Studio 2012 C# console application project which use COM-registered Object through project references.

But now I have to convert it into ASP.NET web application and I can not understand how to use COM Object.

To convert my console application I just configured IIS server to work with my new folder and I'm writing code in Notepad++.

Making

```
using CRKServer;
...
```

Gives me a following error:

```
CS0246: Can not find name or namespace "CRKServer".
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason you are using Notepad++ instead of Visual Studio? If you are using VS, simply add a reference to your COM component (the same way you did in your console app).

Comment: @DirkVollmar, thank you for an answer. I'll try to make it in VS.